# Getting Connection timed out error for flutter app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Getting this error on flutter while running node APIS

`SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = mydomain.com, port = 47260`

So we are getting this error for random api calls, suddenly it gives this error and after refresh its giving success response, not able to identify the issue.

```
var serverApp=app.listen(port, () => {});
serverApp.on('connection', function(socket) {
  serverApp.setTimeout(600 * 60 * 1000);
})
 serverApp.keepAliveTimeout = 3000; 
 serverApp.headersTimeout = 32000; 
 serverApp.timeout = 0;
 serverApp.requestTimeout = 3200;
 serverApp.keepAlive=true;
```

Tried above settings for timeout still getting error

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explore it more. Finally, we sorted it out. It may not be a good practice but at least worked.

We request data again from after 2 secs of timer, if there occurs some error. So typically, while loader is showing to user and there is the error (connection timed out), we just request the data again from the app. So at least end users gets the required data.